# Why does Collections#shuffle not use ThreadLocalRandom?

Tags: java, random, collections, shuffle

```
public static void shuffle(List<?> list) {
    Random rnd = r;
    if (rnd == null)
        r = rnd = new Random(); // harmless race.
    shuffle(list, rnd);
}

private static Random r;
```

I noticed that `Collections#shuffle` uses `new Random()` instead of `ThreadLocalRandom.current()`, and I'm curious as to why.  I wrote a benchmark comparing the two, and the method that uses `ThreadLocalRandom.current()` is faster for each iteration.  Here's the benchmark:

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@Warmup(iterations = 15, time = 500, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 20, time = 500, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@Fork(5)
public class MyBenchmark {
    @Param({"10", "1000", "100000"})
    private int i;

    private List<Integer> list;

    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    @Setup
    public void initialize() {
        list = ThreadLocalRandom.current()
                                .ints(i)
                                .boxed()
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        org.openjdk.jmh.Main.main(args);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public List<Integer> oldMethod() {
        Collections.shuffle(list, RANDOM);
        return list;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public List<Integer> newMethod() {
        Collections.shuffle(list, ThreadLocalRandom.current());
        return list;
    }
}
```

And the results:

```
Benchmark                 (i)  Mode  Cnt        Score       Error  Units
MyBenchmark.newMethod      10  avgt  100       60.802 ±     0.785  ns/op
MyBenchmark.newMethod    1000  avgt  100     6879.496 ±    15.638  ns/op
MyBenchmark.newMethod  100000  avgt  100  1248858.889 ± 33632.559  ns/op
MyBenchmark.oldMethod      10  avgt  100       90.636 ±     1.379  ns/op
MyBenchmark.oldMethod    1000  avgt  100     9740.442 ±    57.373  ns/op
MyBenchmark.oldMethod  100000  avgt  100  1511428.034 ± 27744.775  ns/op
```

So, why is `new Random()` used over `ThreadLocalRandom.current()`?

My guesses:

- This method has not been updated since the release of `ThreadLocalRandom` in JDK 1.7
- `new Random()` is used for thread-safety?

Comment: I'd guess it is the first of your guesses. Java is full of legacy code that could (anf even should) be reworked but is not for compatibility reasons.

Comment: Most likely? The JDK designers didn't want to build a `ThreadLocal` based memory leak into the Collections API..

Comment: AFAICT the java developers don't have a publicly stated policy on rewriting bugfree code to take advantage of later (and perhaps better) APIs. If there really isn't such a public policy, this is really asking for people's opinions about whether to rewrite, which is off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 3):

The `Collections.shuffle(List)` and `Collections.shuffle(List, Random)` methods were added in JDK 1.2, whereas the `ThreadLocalRandom` class wasn't added until Java 7. Thus, for all the releases prior to Java 7, `shuffle(List)` used an instance of `Random`.

Although the source of randomness for `shuffle(List)` isn't specified, it would have possibly have been an unexpected change in behavior for it to be changed to use a different source of randomness. Thus, the method has been left as it stands, using an instance of `Random`.

There's no great need to change it. Other sources of randomness, such as `ThreadLocalRandom` and `SecureRandom`, are subclasses of `Random`, and they can be used for shuffling using the two-arg overload `shuffle(List, Random)` if that's what the application needs.